# Asymptotic behaviour of an integral depending on a parameter

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I am trying to compute the asymptotics on $t$ of the following integral:
\begin{equation}
I(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e^{-|\lambda|^{2}/2t}\prod_{i<j}\left( e^{\lambda_{j}/t}-e^{\lambda_{i}/t} \right)d\lambda.
\end{equation}
According to the [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0246020399800107) I am reading, it suffices to consider the leading nonzero term in the product $\prod_{i<j}\left( e^{\lambda_{j}/t}-e^{\lambda_{i}/t} \right)$. Given that this claim is true, this leads to an easier computation of the integral. However, I do not understand why the claim is correct. According to the paper, once $t$ is fixed, if $|\lambda|^{2}$ is much larger than $t$, the exponential term in the integral will decay exponentially fast, and in particular

> "$\lambda_{i}/t$ can be assumed to be $O(t^{1/2-\epsilon})$".

I don't see why this last statement is true, nor how it implies the claim. I have tried splitting the integral in two, one with the nonzero leading term of the integrand and other with the rest, but I have not succeeded in proving that this second integral does not contribute to the asymptotics. I also have doubts regarding the quoted statement; if we are considering asymptotics on $t$, is it "legal" to study the behaviour of $\lambda_{i}/t$?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: $|\lambda|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2 a$nd $d\lambda=d\lambda_1....d\lambda_n$? do you consider $t\rightarrow 0$ or $t\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. The integral is with respect to the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure $d\lambda=d\lambda_{1}\dots d\lambda_{n}$ and $|\lambda|^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}^{2}$. I am interested in the behaviour of the integral for large values of $t$, i.e. $t\rightarrow\infty$.